# Using HTML5 video tag in a javafx application

Tags: java, html, webview, javafx, javafx-2

I have a simple javaFX application that loads a webpage in a `WebView` componant.

```
StackPane root = new StackPane();
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 80, 20);
browser = new WebView();
webEngine = browser.getEngine();

webEngine.load("test.html");
root.getChildren().add(browser);
jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
```

This works fine and `test.html` can be seen. The issue is with the HTML5 video on the page.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
    <source src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The page works in Chrome 16, but in the java application you can only see the controls and clicking play does nothing. I assume the WebEngine allows HTML5 as the controls appear and the text inside the `<video></video>` tags isn't output.

Can anyone shed some light on what I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to provide a second source with a diffferent codec. maybe, the used codec isn't supported.

Comment: I've tried several videos, all of different types, with the same result. I will carry one trying but I'm not convinced its a codec issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are encountering a codec issue.

From the [JavaFX FAQ question 7](http://javafx.com/faq/), JavaFX (as of 2.0.2) only supports flv videos encoded using the [on2 vp6 codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP6).

Additional codec support is scheduled for future releases.  The relevant feature request is [RT-18296](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18296) (login required, but anybody can sign up to view the JavaFX issue database and create feature requests, vote for issues or post comments).

A related StackOverflow question provides a [summary of considerations for playing video in JavaFX 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440152/any-simple-and-up-to-date-java-frameworks-for-embedding-movies-within-a-swing/10441210#10441210) (including a JavaFX WebView).

To demonstrate a html5 video tag and video playback within a JavaFX WebEngine, run the following code, which plays an Oracle supplied vp6 encoded video.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class WebViewVideo extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { Application.launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    WebView root = new WebView();
    root.getEngine().loadContent(
      "<video width='320' height='240'controls='controls'>" +
        "<source src='http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv'/>" + 
        "Your browser does not support the video tag." + 
      "</video>");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 340, 260));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Then I suppose it's safe to say that JavaFX doesn't really support HTML5. As HTML5 shouldn't in itself care what codecs JavaFX can/cannot support, but the OS. Luckily as at JavaFX 2.1, there is now support for H.264 (MP4) video, so this makes things much less painful. :)

Comment: Can you use the loop attribute in the video tag? When I use the loop attribute, it won't loop :(

Comment: To answer my question, it was the version of JavaFX I was using. I upgraded to Java8 and everything is fine. mp4 videos work, and looping does as well.