# JavaFx and playing HD movies under Ubuntu - low FPS

Tags: media, h.264, javafx-2

I have been developing an application in JavaFx 2.x which is able to play movies. For what I have understand, the only valid movie format supported by this platform is `H.264/MPEG-4`.
Now, under Windows it works pretty well, but when I run exact same code under Ubuntu - the FPS is noticeable. It's not a huge difference, but one can certainly spot it and thus - make watching uncomfortable.

I'm noticing it on my laptop (2xCores and built-in, standard VGA card), on PC (4xCores + ATI Radeon) it's less noticeable.

My question is - **is there any way to improve this FPS factor under Linux**? Maybe choosing some special distribution? Maybe installing some other codecs? Maybe it's JavaFx 2.x under Linux thing and will be improved in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the only valid movie format supported by this platform is H.264/MPEG-4.

The platform also supports the VP6 codec.

There is a Stack Overflow answer which summarizes [JavaFX 2.1 video playback capabilities and considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440152/any-simple-and-up-to-date-java-frameworks-for-embedding-movies-within-a-swing/10441210#10441210).  The answer includes a sample application which plays back of a VP6 encoded video.

> Maybe it's JavaFx 2.x under Linux thing and will be improved in this regard?

Could be, JavaFX on Linux is just a developer preview at the moment.

> under Windows it works pretty well, but when I run exact same code under Ubuntu - the FPS is noticeable.

Try the latest [JavaFX developer preview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html).  If you are still getting choppy framerates under Ununtu then create a [jira issue](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com), attaching your *short* video and *short* sample player code.