# Java and video player

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any simple (and up to date) Java frameworks for embedding movies within a Swing Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440152/any-simple-and-up-to-date-java-frameworks-for-embedding-movies-within-a-swing)

I need to implement such situation, in full screen on desktop, some player playing the video, and during some periods of time my java program has to show some text in some part of screen appearing with animation and after that again hides. But during all the time the video has to be continue playing in full screen.

Which suggestion could you give me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try it myself, but I think you may find this useful:
http://lobobrowser.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/javafx-video-in-a-swing-application-technically-doable/

If you don't know javaFX, you can try out [JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html), it is relatively easy and you don't need to learn a new ttechnology. Here is a tutorial on playing video using JMF: http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060422/PlayingVideowithJMF/ . But as far as I know, there are some problems in JMF and oracle has no plan to improve it in future.