# Play a Youtube video using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to play a video from youtube using javaFX. Here is my code

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Media");
    Group root = new Group();
    Media media = new Media("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0BWlvnBmIE");
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaPlayer.play();

    MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

    root.getChildren().add(mediaView);
    Scene scene = SceneBuilder.create().width(500).height(500).root(root)
            .fill(Color.WHITE).build();
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

}
```

The window opens but video doesn't play and there is no exception. What is the problem and how can i fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: check this link :https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/6jb4ep/is_it_possible_to_watchload_youtube_videos_in_java/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Update Oct 2021*

I tried this solution again using JavaFX 17, it worked fine for me, which is kind of nice six years later.

Note that the video in the original example is no longer hosted on YouTube, but you would want to play a different video anyway.

To do so, just substitute the video id part of the url `utUPth77L_o` with the id of your video (which you can see in the url when you play it in YouTube).

Example URLs which worked in 2021:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P_tAU3GM9XI
- https://www.youtube.com/embed/P_tAU3GM9XI?autoplay=1

The `watch` linked videos display the full YouTube site, the `embed` linked videos just display the YouTube player for the video.

YouTube does force some videos to be displayed on its site rather than using the embed link, so even if the video can be watched on YouTube via the watch URL, the embed link won't always work, but the watch link should work OK in WebView for such cases.

*Update Dec 4th 2015*

Some versions of JavaFX 8 are unable to play back youtube video content. Currently, for instance, Java 8u66 cannot playback youtube video content, but Java 8u72 early access release can.

**Background**

General information on playing video in JavaFX is located in my answer to: [Any simple (and up to date) Java frameworks for embedding movies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441210/1155209).  This answer just deals with embedding YouTube videos as that appears to be what the question asker is interested in.

**Solution**

JavaFX can play a YouTube video using a YouTube video URL if you supply the URL to a [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) rather than a [MediaPlayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html).

**Considerations**

If you just want the YouTube media player and not the whole related YouTube page, use the `/embed` location rather than the `/watch` location in the URL.

Only some videos can be embedded.  For instance, you can't embed the Katy Perry video because YouTube blocks it's distribution in an embedded format (instead telling you to view the video on the YouTube site, where it is only provided through the YouTube Flash player).

Only videos which YouTube allow to play in their HTML5 player may be played in JavaFX.  This is a pretty large percentage of YouTube videos.  YouTube videos which only play in YouTube's Flash player do not play in JavaFX.

**Sample Application**

The JavaFX application below plays a YouTube video advertisement for a piece of fruit.

[image: fruit]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class VideoPlayer extends Application {    
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    WebView webview = new WebView();
    webview.getEngine().load(
      "http://www.youtube.com/embed/utUPth77L_o?autoplay=1"
    );
    webview.setPrefSize(640, 390);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(webview));
    stage.show();
  }    
}
```

Comment: Hi Jewelsea, I am using same code in our application but this code is not able to play youtube video. Application view is successfully open but after giving error message when its try to  play. we are facing some this kind of  error in the view section Error:- "An error occurred. Please try again later". So please let me what is the exact problem.

Comment: I just tried running the code from my answer again on Java 8u40 on OS X 10.9.5 and the video played perfectly fine.

Comment: would there be any way to cast the Webview node into a Media

Comment: @Hilea No, I don't think you can cast the WebView node into a Media node.

Answer (score 3):

JavaFX can't play youtube video just with the video url. you need to specify the file of your video, not just a random youtube link.
Try with this URL : http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv
your code works fine

Comment: Note: Recent JavaFX versions no longer support `flv` playback (`mp4` files should play back fine).  Playing videos via YouTube watch and embed URLs loaded into WebView (as demonstrated in my answer) also works, in addition to URLs directly pointing to video files as demonstrated in this answer.