# JavaFX Webview youtube video error

Tags: java, webview, youtube, javafx

When I try to load a video into JavaFX Webview the youtube will display an error message when play is pressed saying:
"An error occurred, please try again later"

I have this:

```
private void change(final Pattern pattern) {
    nameLabel.setText(pattern.getName());
    final WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
    final String code = "YME_DYsmBpY";
    engine.load("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + code + "?rel=0;3&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0");
}
```

The WebView (view) is created in FXML and is not used outside of this method.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Although playing YouTube videos using JavaFX used to work in earlier JavaFX versions, I don't believe it works in the current JavaFX version (8u25) on all platforms.

See related bug report:

- [RT-35062 [WebNode] jfxwebkit.dll crash when playing Youtube videos in WebView](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-35062)

The above bug report is logged against Windows 7.

I tried my old solution to:

- [Play a video using javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758041/play-a-video-using-javafx)

The code for this solution is in the linked question and is very similar to the code in your question.

This solution plays a video using YouTube running under an embedded WebView control.  And that worked on OS X 10.9, Java 8u20.  The program output to the console weird messages: "Outstanding resource locks detected" as described in RT-35062, but otherwise seemed to execute OK and displayed the video fine.  So I guess the potential JVM crash referenced in RT-35062 is environment specific.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure YouTube embed URLs can't be loaded into a WebView like that...

Try using the iframe markup (you can get an example on the regular YouTube page for most videos) with a call to engine.loadContent() instead.  For example:

```
engine.loadContent("<html><body><iframe width=\"1000\" height=\"500\" " +
            "src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + code + "?rel=0;3&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0\" frameborder=\"0\" ></iframe></body></html>");
```

I haven't tested the snippet above, but barring a typo or two in the string literal I expect it to work.