# Playing a YouTube video with JavaFX

Tags: java, video, javafx, youtube, media-player

I've watched a lot of posts about playing YouTube videos, and also watched Oracle learning tutorials. They used this code and it worked perfectly to them, but I get errors. And can't find a way to fix it.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage window) throws Exception
{

    Media media = new Media("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0oIoR9mLwc");
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
    player.setAutoPlay(true);

    StackPane sp = new StackPane(view);

    Scene sc = new Scene(sp,500,500);

    window.setScene(sc);
    window.show();
}
```

ERRORS I GET

```
    Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported protocol "https"
        at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at PlayVideo.Main.start(Main.java:34)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
    Exception running application PlayVideo.Main
```

I also checked this link on stackoverflow but couldn't find solution. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758041/play-a-video-using-javafx)

Also tried it this way but video won't load.

```
@Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        WebView webview = new WebView();
        webview.getEngine().load(
                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaPUbzfJx2A"
        );
        webview.setPrefSize(640, 390);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(webview));
        stage.show();
      } 
 }
```

Comment: > but i get errors  
Tell us about the errors please.

Comment: If you get errors, it would be easier to help you if you posted the errors in the question.

Comment: Check it now, i edited my question

Comment: Any help guys ? @MrPixelDream

Comment: According to the Exception you are seeing, SSL is not supported. Try "http" instead of "https" on your video link.

Comment: which java version you have?

Comment: @GoXr3Plus Java 8 version 73

Comment: @MrPixelDream When i remove that s, there are no errors, but anyway application doesnt load. I get blank window

Comment: I tried copying and pasting both examples and had no video, but also no errors for the media player example, however for the webview it worked perfectly and displayed youtube's search bar etc using JDK 8/JRE 1.8_091 so could not duplicate any error....- Also note MrPixelDream's comment, that https is not supported by media player and youtube.com redirects requests to https:// protocol